# My method does not return lists. What should i do?

Tags: python, list, function, return

My method looks like below. I am trying to return a string and a list. But it does not return anything. I put a print statement to check but the program doesnot enter the print statement, let alone execute the return statement below it.

```
    def frame_array(self, text_file_path):
        text_file = os.path.join(text_file_path, os.listdir(text_file_path)[0])
        with open(text_file, "r", encoding="utf8") as file:
            for line in file:
                if line[0] == "#":
                    self.file_name = line.split("/")[7]
                    count = 0
                else:
                    list_of_items = line[:-2].split(
                        ","
                    )
                    count += 1
                    vec_list = []
                    for i in range(19):
                        vec_list.append(float(list_of_items[i + 1]))
                    self.vec_lists.append(vec_list)
        print("vec list created\nOK")
        return self.file_name, self.vec_lists
```

```
self.vec_lists = [] # is an instance defined in the class.
```

This is my class:

```
class AudioFeature:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cfg = util.config_loader("config.yaml")
        self.wav_info = {}
        self.beat_info = {}
        self.seg_info = {}
        self.vec_lists = []
```

In the same class, in another method i have called `frame_array()` as below. It throws an exception, which means the return statement is not being executed at all.

```
        try:
            file_name, vec_lists = self.frame_array(self.cfg["text_file_directory"])
        except Exception:
            print("Text file directory missing")
```

The `self.cfg` instance loads config yaml file where the configuration for text file directory is as:

```
text_file_directory: "./data/text_data"
```

Note: Just examining the variable values of `self.vec_lists`. It looks like this:
[image]
But i need this to be returned by the method.

Comment: Please show a *complete* example. I can't even tell what class this is in, let alone how I would use it, or how you are trying to use it. Right now, you haven't even shown us verification that `frame_array` gets called in the first place.

Comment: I don't understand well your query. Can you be more explicit about your problem? Actually, you returning a `tuple` implicitly, the first element being your filename, and the second, your list.

Comment: In addition, if `frame_array` does get called somewhere, it will either reach that `print()` statement, or it will throw an exception, since it doesn't exit or return anywhere in the rest of the method. If it does throw an exception, you should provide a full stracktrace.

Comment: I have modified the explanation of the problem. Please have a look.

Comment: Can you please provide the minimal reproducible example?